# Why is my ListView duplicating items on button press?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a game where all the players are hooked up to a Firebase database.

I have a `ListView` which displays the players. Right now it's only 4 dummy accounts that I made.

When the score of any player in the database changes, it refreshes the listview. There's a button to increase your score by 1. If you click that button too fast, you'll get duplicates in the listview.

I think I see the problem. Somehow it depends on how many times you press the button while the data is being fetched. If I do a double press while the datas loading, it'll duplicate each item, So I'll have 8 items in the list. How can I stop this?

This is my firebase:

```
root
|____scores
|    |____ID1: Score
|    |____ID2:Score
|
|____users
     |____ID1:
     |    |____firstName:
     |    |____lastName:
     |    |____score:
     |____ID2:
          |____firstName:
          |____lastName:
          |____score:
```

So yeah, I write to 2 locations when I write scores.

scoreRef points to the scores branch
usersListRef points to the second "users branch"

```java
scoreRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//INSERT A LOT OF CODE UNRELATED, HERE
//Tryna list all users in the database and their scores in an arrayAdapter                  
              userLeaderboard.clear();
                    leaderboardAdapter.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        usersListRef.child(snapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                Map<String, Object> userCredMap = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                userLeaderboard.add(<CONTACENATION OF NAME AND SCORE>));
                                leaderboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem relies on pressing multiple times the button, do this.

When you press the button, disable the button with

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

When the database process is complete, inside your:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Doing this, you can't prevent the button being clicked when the action is still waiting for results from the database.

Remember to handle also the failures of the database enablind the button again.

Another tip is to disable the button while the data is beign fetched and then enable it when the data has been fetched from the database, then you can prevent a race condition there.

Comment: Thing is, that would limit the speed the User can play. I don't think that should happen just because their internet may be slow. Isn't there a way that allows the user to click as fast as they can, but not duplicate the listview? What _is_ duplicating the listview?

Comment: Yes, you can write the changes locally, wait for the fetch transaction to be done and then send all the points as one request

Comment: also how would I do that if the buttons disabled. I wouldn't recieve button clicks

Comment: you can leave the button enabled, while receiving your data, you do not push at the same time and keep the clicks locally, then you send them out to the database as one request

Comment: But wouldn't that slow down the database refresh speed? It'd look like I suddenly just jumped up 10 points in one go. I chose realtime database so I could have a real time leaderboard. Isn't there a way to properly draw the listview without it somehow adding 2 items to the list?